# Why does my JAVA_HOME point to jre instead of jdk?

Tags: java, maven, manjaro, arch

I want to compile a project on my manjaro system using mvn and every time I get this error:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK, not a JRE
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: FYI, this error is thrown in all cases when `JAVA_HOME` _does not_ point to a JDK installation including the case when it points to a non-existing folder.

Comment: @Alex yes, but there was both java jdk and jre already installed on my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution myself:

```
sudo archlinux-java set <target java package name>
```

For Example:

```
sudo archlinux-java set java-15-jdk
```

Found this here: https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/02/install-java-arch/